# Babel JS babel-preset-php error

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, babeljs

I was just trying the new Babel's babel-preset-php (https://gitlab.com/kornelski/babel-preset-php#php7-to-es7-syntax-translator). I did everything in the README file, I installed the preset with `npm i -S babel-preset-php`. Then I created a `.babelrc` file with the following contents;

```
{
    "presets": ["php"]
}
```

Installed the cli with `npm i -g babel-cli`. Then I created a simple PHP file that only contains a simple function:

```
<?php

function addCalculator($x, $y)
{
    return $x + $y;
}
```

And tried to run the transpiler with `babel number.php -o file.js`. But I get an error in the execution of the script:

```
/home/claudio/Documents/Development/babel/node_modules/babel-preset-php/lib/plugins.js:6
        Identifier(p) {
                  ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( (While processing preset: "/home/claudio/Documents/Development/babel/node_modules/babel-preset-php/index.js")
at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/claudio/Documents/Development/babel/node_modules/babel-preset-php/index.js:1:79)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

I'm not that experient with nodejs and npm, so any idea on what might be happening?

Comment: Are you using webpack?

Comment: I'm not that experienced with the Node workflow. I just followed the instructions in the README file. So I guess I'm not using webpack.

Comment: What versions of node and babel are you using? You can find out by running `node --version` and `babel --version`.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Ok, I just realized that you are calling a **public function** outside of a class. That's not correct PHP. You can't define a function as public outside of a class. Your PHP code is just wrong.

Comment: `babel Number.php -o --presets=php file.js` returns `file.js does not exist`. Wasn't it supposed to be created?

Comment: You have to write: `babel Number.php -o file.js --presets=php`. Currently you are putting the second option between the key and value of the first one. Check my edited answer.

Comment: I corrected the PHP code, and called like you said, but still getting the same `Unexpected token` error.

Comment: And there is still a `Identifier(p)` in the error message? Or did the message change? As I understood it, `Identifier(p)` refers to **p**ublic

Answer (score 2):

The error is being emitted before it even touches your PHP code. It is, in fact, erroring on [this particular line](https://gitlab.com/kornelski/babel-preset-php/blob/master/lib/plugins.js#L6) of `babel-preset-php` itself:

```
return {
    visitor: {
        Identifier(p) { // This is the invalid line
            if (p.node.name != 'Exception' || p.scope.hasBinding("Exception")) {
                return;
            }
```

This preset is using the shorthand object initializers added in ECMAScript 2015. What is probably happening here is that your local Javascript environment does not support ES2015 syntax.

I would recommend updating `node` and `babel` to the latest versions and trying again.